# Unable to send file to ruby on rails backend with formdata

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I have this code in my react application:

```
this.handlefileupload = (e) => {



console.log(e.target.files[0])
 var formdata = new FormData()
      


      formdata.append('file', e.target.files[0])

   

      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/upload_document', {
        myfile: formdata
      }, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem('loginToken'),
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
        }
      )
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('success')

        }

        )
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error.response);
        });
    }
```

And then I have the following in my Ruby on Rails application:

```
def upload
   uploaded_io = params[:myfile][:file]
   File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
     file.write(uploaded_io.read)
   end
end
```

I am getting the following error:

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):

It is most likely because it is not receiving the file?

Comment: Now I am getting just an empty line with i do puts()

Answer (score 0):

Your params in backend `params[:files][:file]`

But you are sending it from react as `params[:file]`

**Change react code to** `formdata.append('files[file]', e.target.files[0])`

Also, make sure **URL** is valid!

```
const formData = new FormData();
const headers = {
  'Authorization': "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem('loginToken'),
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}

formdata.append('files[file]', e.target.files[0])
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/upload_document", formData, {headers})
```

Comment: Okay, now I am getting just the empty line when I do puts()

Comment: make sure `e.target.files[0]` contains file

Comment: It does, I do know what to do, I have been trying to fix this for two days now.

Comment: @danny.j back-end server request log